# AWS region wise Fault tolerance

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, fault-tolerance

Motive: Tried Muti-AZ Fault tolerance for a word-press website, It worked fine. Now trying to achieve region wise Fault tolerance for the same website.

Problem faced: The new word-press website which I am trying to build is not getting connected.

The details are as follows

EC-2 Instance - Amazon Linux

Primary site - North California [old one] - successfully working

Secondary Site - North Virginia [New one] - Not working even either for simple[Stanalone] or even for weighted routing.

DB name is same in both regions.

I tried the following

1. I copied the EC2 AMI to another region [North Virginia]
2. Took a snapshot of the existing working RDS DB [from North California] and copied it to the new region[North Virginia]
3. Restored the snapshot in the new region [North Virginia]
4. SSH'ed into the North virginia ec2 INSTANCE and nano'ed into wp-config.php under /var/www/html and changed the DB-ENDPOINT to the new RDS DB
5. Rest all AWS service is an exact replica of the first site [like VPC, Security Groups, IAM ..etc]
6. Route-53 - I tried both, simple routing as well as weighted routing

   - Simple routing to the new site doesn't work at all
   - weighted routing works for the old site, but not to the new one
7. No error messages, the moment I enter the site name it tries to connect for some time and blanks out
8. I was able to log in to the DB[MYSQL] from the EC2 instance.

Pls Help

Comment: Double check that your security group is correct for the new region's VPC. Your problem sounds like port 80 or 443 is being blocked.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I have even tried allowing all traffic on both sides. Still, it dint work.Should be changing something in the database or anything in wp-config.php?

Comment: Create a test HTML page on the server - just a simple page and not a WordPress page. Can you access the test page? If that works, then create a simple PHP page.

Comment: Thanks, John, Will try that in some time and keep this post updated.